# Target class [AdminController] does not exist

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, laravel

[image]I have this error when a user returns from login to the admin page (i.e http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin), it should throw a 403 error if he/she doesn't sign in as the admin (i.e if he is not the admin)

Admin also experience this same error

Here's My Route
Laravel Version: 9.24.0

Please anyone should help
Here are my codes on web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
  

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
    return view('dashboard');
})->middleware(['auth'])->name('dashboard');

Route::middleware(['auth','admin'])->name('admin.')->prefix('admin')->group(function() {
    Route::get('/', [AdminController::class, 'index'])->name('index');
});
require __DIR__.'/auth.php';
```

Comment: You did not import that AdminController

Comment: You need to use the full namespace in your Route::get,  or add the full namespace with a `use` statement at the top.

Comment: I'm just 2days in learning this, i have added this but it's still not working
"use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route\AdminController"

Comment: That's not the name space for your AdminController. It's most likely something like `App\Http\Controllers\AdminController`, but you can double-check your namespace at the top of your AdminController

Comment: thank you @aynber, I'm still experiencing the same problem

<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
Use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AdminController;

Answer (score 0):

in **app\Providers\RouteServiceProvider.php**

uncomment this line

```
protected $namespace = 'App\\Http\\Controllers';
```

[image: 1]

**then command do**

```
php artisan optimize
// or 
php artisan optimize:clear
```

Answer (score -1):

Thank you everyone for your help
I have identified the problem, I didn't add this on my kernel

```
'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\Admin::class
```