# Unable to change default routes in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am new in Laravel and working on laravel 8, Right now i am trying to change "Default routes",But i am getting following error
Target class [AdminController] does not exist.
Here is my code in "web.php"

```
use App\Http\Controllers\AdminController;
Route::get('/', 'AdminController@index')->name('admin');
```

Here is my "AdminController.php",how can we do this ? Thanks in advance

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class AdminController extends Controller
{
   public function index()
     {
        echo "Hello world";
     }   
}
```

Comment: try Route::get('/', [AdminController::class,'index'])->name('admin');

Comment: If in doubt read the docs for the version you are using and not some old tutorial

Comment: see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/73306452/15186994

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Laravel 8 release note : [Routing Namespace Updates](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/releases#routing-namespace-updates)

**Routing Namespace Updates**

In previous releases of Laravel, the `RouteServiceProvider` contained a `$namespac`e property. This property's value would automatically be prefixed onto controller route definitions and calls to the action helper / `URL::action` method. In `Laravel 8.x,` this property is null by default. This means that no automatic namespace prefixing will be done by Laravel. Therefore, in new `Laravel 8.x` applications, controller route definitions should be defined using standard PHP callable syntax:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;
 
Route::get('/users', [UserController::class, 'index']);
```

Calls to the action related methods should use the same callable syntax:

```
action([UserController::class, 'index']);



return Redirect::action([UserController::class, 'index']);
```

If you prefer `Laravel 7.x` style controller route prefixing, you may simply add the `$namespace` property into your application's `RouteServiceProvider`.

This change only affects `new Laravel 8.x applications`. Applications `upgrading from Laravel 7.x` will still have the `$namespace property` in their `RouteServiceProvider`.